# Understanding near call instruction encoding

Tags: assembly, x86

By disassembling some binary code I've found the near call instruction `call 0x8ae` which is encoded as `e8 97 08 00 00`.

Looking at an instruction set reference I've found that these kind of instructions are encoded as:

```
call XX XX XX XX   <==>   e8 XX XX XX XX
```

being `XX XX XX XX` the 32-bit displacement relative to the next instruction.

I don't understand why the disassembled instruction is encoded as `e8 97 08 00 00`. I would have expected an encoding of `e8 ae 08 00 00` instead.

Comment: The address is the *offset* from the current EIP, not an absolute address.  Just as your question says.   A good decompiler will translate it back to the absolute address and generate a label for the target address.  Use a good one.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks a lot! Now it does add up.

Comment: @眠りネロク Consider writing your own answer then!

Comment: You're allowed to accept your own answer as well (click the check mark).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Hans Passant suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276612/understanding-near-call-instruction-encoding#comment77515782_45276612), the 32-bit *relative displacement* the `call` instruction takes is relative to the next instruction and therefore the disassembler translates it to the absolute address it would refer to.

Consider the following disassembled snippet:

```
  Address     Encoded                 Disassembled
  ---------------------------------------------------- 
  12:         e8 97 08 00 00          call   0x8ae
  17:         83 c4 0c                add    $0xc,%esp
```

The relative displacement of the `call` instruction is actually `0x897` as can be seen in the *Encoded* column, but since this *offset* is relative to the `call`'s next instruction, which is located at address `0x17`, then the disassembler displays the result of the sum of the offset (i.e.: `0x897`) and the next instruction's address (i.e.: `0x17`):

`0x897 + 0x17 = 0x8ae`

and this is exactly what the disassembler is actually displaying: `call 0x8ae`.