# How works Mach-O rebasing

Tags: ios, mach-o

I'm new to this. But I want to understand how actually rebasing works in dyld.
Because of ASLR, pointers in text and data segments become invalid.
So we need to fix them. We can fix pointers in data segment because it has read-write permissions, and this segment becomes dirty. But how we can fix pointers in text segment?
text segment is read-executable

Comment: What makes you think there are pointers in the text segment?

Comment: @Siguza For example in our binary text segment, we have assembly instruction to call our function `callq 0x100000e80`, but with ASLR address 0x100000e80 is not valid. So we need rebasing it. And how this rebasing happens in text segment?

Comment: That's encoded as a relative offset, it's just your disassembler showing an absolute address. If you dump the bytes of such an instruction, you'll find that it's exactly the same regardless of load address.

Comment: @Siguza It turns out that text and data segments have relative offsets? If yes, why data segment have to rebase, but text don't ?
Or is there any article where I can find out more about this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45276612/2302862

Comment: @Siguza As I understand, text section contains relative addresses i.e. its just offset for current instruction pointer. So they don't need to be rebased. But data segment contains pointer, which usually address somewhere. So after ASLR pointers in data segment becomes invalid and we have to rebase them. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dyldinfo -rebase` to see the pointers that need to be rebased

```
$ xcrun dyldinfo -rebase /bin/ls
for arch x86_64:
rebase information (from compressed dyld info):
segment section          address     type         value
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008040  pointer  0x10000766E
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008048  pointer  0x100007678
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008050  pointer  0x100007682
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008058  pointer  0x10000768C
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008060  pointer  0x100007696
...
```

As we can see, only pointers in `__DATA` or `__DATA_CONST` need to be rebased. They're all absolute addresses. The reason that code in `__TEXT` doesn't need rebasing is because of **RIP-relative addressing** -- all pointers within `__TEXT` segment is relative to the instruction pointer. This kind of binary is called PIE (position-independent executable).

Answer (score 1):

Roovent, your answer was *exactly* what I was looking for when I went searching for this information -- thank you!!

For those coming along in (mid- or late-) 2022, here's a bit of an update:

The command is now known as `dyld_info` and the parameter is `-fixups`. So, you would run it like:

`$ xcrun dyld_info -fixups /bin/ls`

(Writing from a machine running a beta of macOS so ymmv. I hope this helps someone)